# A restricted summation over a function of integer n-tuple

Tags: summation

I want to sum over a function of n-tuple like so:

$\sum\limits_{a\leq k_1+k_2+...+k_n\leq b}f(\{k_i\}_{i=1}^{n})$

where each $k_i$ is non-negative, i.e. $k_i\geq0 \;\forall\;i $

**An Example:**

Say, we want to evaluate $\sum\limits_{2\leq k_1+k_2+k_3\leq5}k_1^{k_1!}k_2^{k_2!}k_3^{k_3!}$

*My attempt:*

```
f[k_List]:=Product[Power[k[[i]],Factorial[k[[i]]]],{i,1,Length@k}];
tuplelist[x_,n_]:=Sequence @@ Permutations[Join[#, ConstantArray[0, n - Length@#]]] & /@ IntegerPartitions[x, n];
Total@Table[Total@(f[#]&/@tuplelist[i,3]),{i,2,5}]    
(*2248*)
```

Please suggest if there are ways to modify the existing `Sum[]` function or other efficient ways to do this. Looking forward to a variety of techniques!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Anjan Kumar's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/167969/531) is good, but if you want to be able to give the function an expression (like with an ordinary `Sum`), here's one possibility (**edited** to make use of [J. M.'s suggestion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/167987/531) of [`FrobeniusSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrobeniusSolve.html)):

```
ClearAll[SumOverIntegerPartitions];
Attributes[SumOverIntegerPartitions] = {HoldFirst};
SumOverIntegerPartitions[
   f_, {ks_List, min_Integer?Positive, max_Integer?Positive}] := 
  With[{perms =
     Catenate[
      FrobeniusSolve[ConstantArray[1, Length@ks], #] & /@ 
       Range[min, max]]}, 
   Total[f /. (Thread[ks -> #] & /@ perms)]];
```

Using the same test case:

```
SumOverIntegerPartitions[k1^k1!*k2^k2!*k3^k3!, {{k1, k2, k3}, 2, 5}]
(* 2248 *)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also use `FrobeniusSolve[]` for this sum, since it automatically generates `0` in its tuples, unlike `IntegerPartitions[]`:

```
Sum[Product[k^k!, {k, m}],
    {m, Flatten[Table[FrobeniusSolve[ConstantArray[1, 3], k], {k, 2, 5}], 1]}]
   2248
```

Answer (score 3):

You can modify your code to something like this:

```
f[k_] := Times @@ (#^#! & /@ k);
tuplelist[x_, n_] := Permutations /@ IntegerPartitions[x, {n}, Range[0, x]];
Outer[f, tuplelist[#, 3] & /@ Range[2, 5], 3] // Total[#, 3] &
```

> 2248